# error in pattern recognition and string matching in perl program

Tags: perl

I have write this little program to match a pattern and substitute it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$LOGFILE = "odds.dat";
open(LOGFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
foreach $line (<LOGFILE>) {
($hour, $match, $odd1, $oddx, $odd2, $dummy) = split(/\,/,$line);
($hteam,$ateam) = split(/ § /,$match);
$hteam=get_name($hteam);
$ateam=get_name($ateam);
$match="$hteam - $ateam";
$foo=qq("$hour" "$match" $odd1 $oddx $odd2 \n) ;
print $foo;
               }
sub get_name {
# Return the full name for the team, if it exists, otherwise return the original
my %alias = (
"Atletico-MG" => "Atletico Mineiro",
"Atletico-PR" => "Atletico Paranaense",
...
...
"U.A.N.L.- Tigres" => "U.A.N.L.",
...
...
 );
return $alias{$_[0]} // $_[0];
}
```

where odds.dat is:

```
2011-10-28 20:00 , Atletico-MG § Atletico-PR ,2.00 ,5.00, 6.00
2011-10-28 20:00 ,U.A.N.L.- Tigres § Atletico-MG ,2.00,5.00,6.00
```

but the output is:

```
"2011-10-28 21:15 " " Atletico-MG - Atletico-PR " 2.00  5.00  6.00
"2011-10-28" "U.A.N.L. - Atletico-MG " 2.00 5.00 6.00
```

why  Atletico-MG and Atletico-PR are not recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have whitespace in your team names, e.g. `" Atletico-MG"` does not match `"Atletico-MG"`. This can be removed in the first split. You also do not need to escape the comma:

```
split(/\s*,\s*/,$line);
```

**Elaboration:**

You are not using strict and warnings, which is a bad idea. Using three-argument open and lexical file handle is recommended, and I would recommend using `$!` in your die message, so you know why it fails. I've also tweaked your other split to strip whitespace and limit to two fields (as there are never more than two teams).

You do not need the `$dummy` variable if you are not going to use it, as additional values from the split will be discarded. You will however need to adjust for newlines, otherwise you will sometimes get two. I added `chomp`.

I assume your double quotes around the time and team names are intentional. You might consider printing using tab delimiters. It is fairly readable, and also makes splitting easier in further processing. E.g.:

```
print join "\t", $hour, $match, $odd1, $oddx, $odd2 . "\n";
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $logfile = "odds.dat";
open my $log, '<', $logfile or die "Could not open log file: $!";
foreach my $line (<$log>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($hour, $match, $odd1, $oddx, $odd2) =
        split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
    my ($hteam,$ateam) = split /\s*§\s*/, $match, 2;
    $hteam=get_name($hteam);
    $ateam=get_name($ateam);
    $match = "$hteam - $ateam";
    print qq("$hour" "$match" $odd1 $oddx $odd2\n);
}
sub get_name {
# Return the full name for the team, if it exists,
# otherwise return the original
    my %alias = (
        "Atletico-MG" => "Atletico Mineiro",
        "Atletico-PR" => "Atletico Paranaense",
        "U.A.N.L.- Tigres" => "U.A.N.L.",
    );
    return $alias{$_[0]} // $_[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following debug line to the top of your `get_name` function.

```
warn "In get_name looking for <$_[0]>\n";
```

I think that will make it clear what the problem is.